# How to extract items from a file

Tags: python, dictionary

I am tying to sort this log by location while preserving the order of the time field. I am trying to do this in python.

This is my sample input:

- Chicago 09:00:00
- Phoenix 09:00:03
- Houston 09:00:13
- Chicago 09:00:59
- Houston 09:01:10
- Chicago 09:03:13
- Seattle 09:10:11
- Seattle 09:10:25

And this is what I would like my output to be:

- Chicago 09:00:00
- Chicago 09:00:59
- Chicago 09:03:13
- Houston 09:00:13
- Houston 09:01:10
- Phoenix 09:00:03
- Seattle 09:10:11
- Seattle 09:10:25

This is what I am currently doing:

```
def read_file(file_name):
    file = open(file_name, 'r')
    lines = file.read().split()
    file.close()

    return lines
```

and this is what that returns:

```
['Chicago', '09:00:00', 'Phoenix', '09:00:03', 'Houston', '09:00:13', 'Chicago', '09:00:59', 'Houston', '09:01:10', 'Chicago', '09:03:13', 'Seattle', '09:10:11', 'Seattle', '09:10:25']
```

How would I create a dictonary for the locations and time to then sort them using a merge sort algorithm?

Also, open to suggestions if a dictory is not the best way to go.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since text extraction is a very format-sensitive thing, I recommend showing your input data as a backtick-fenced monospace code block. It's hard to tell what sort of string we're really parsing otherwise. Having said that, it looks like you can simply read the file into a list and call `sort` on it (Python uses Timsort internally--not sure why you need merge sort specifically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your desired output is simply the sorted lines:

```
def read_file(file_name):
    file = open(file_name, 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    return sorted(lines)
```